# Bootstrap grid inside re-sizable panels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dojo

I'm adding some new content to an old page that uses the Dojo library to create 2 panels, with a spacer in between that can be dragged left/right to expand/contract the panels. Think of it like a code editor with a split view between 2 files.

I was trying to put a form in one of the panels, and have it such that the form elements and labels stack when the panel gets small enough:

```html
<form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label for="ID">Identifier</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select name="ID" id="ID">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label for="Direction">Direction</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select name="Direction" id="Direction">
                        <option value="ASCENDING">ASCENDING</option>
                        <option value="DESCENDING">DESCENDING</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I noticed however that when resizing the panels, the grid behaviour wouldn't apply. It only applied when I actually resized the entire window.

Does bootstrap only use the size of the window for its grid, or can it be made such that it responds to a dynamically changing size of its parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bootstap's grid system of 12 columns is based on the device or viewport size (i.e. Window size, or the visible page area inside window).

Here is for your reference

- `.col-xs-` : Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
- `.col-sm-` : Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- `.col-md-` : Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- `.col-lg-` : Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

if you are using v.3, here is the doc to refer [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)